# preg_replace with :alnum: and UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace

I discovered that using the `u` modifier is helping sometimes when working with UTF-8 strings but on my Linux server it replaces the umlaut with `-` instead leaving it like on my Windows server.

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
function clean($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/ui', '-', $string);
}
echo clean("Test: föG");
```

Linux:
`Test--f-G`

Windows (as it should):
`Test--föG`

Comment: What happens if you changed the UTF-8 to something other than that? For example `charset=windows-1252`.

Comment: You mean `mb_internal_encoding('windows-1252')`? Doesn't change anything...

Comment: Something like that. Have you tried removing it altogether?

Comment: Also removing that line doesn't change anything.

Comment: What if you tried using `utf8_encode` somehow?

Comment: Then I get that: `Test--f--G`

Comment: Are you using this in a database by any chance?

Comment: Nope, plain PHP string. The file itself is also in utf8 and the charset in the browser and the output in the browser also utf8 as charset.

Comment: @David: works here on linux; check that $string is utf-8. What's the output of `bin2hex($string)` ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP documentation of the PCRE module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php):

> In UTF-8 mode, characters with values greater than 128 do not match any of the POSIX character classes.

This is probably because of efficiency reasons: there are *many* Unicode characters. You can write your regular expression using the Unicode character properties instead of the POSIX character class. This will be somewhat slower though.

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
function clean($string) {
        return preg_replace('/[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]/ui', '-', $string);
}
echo clean("Test: föG");
```

Comment: Make sure to handle combining diacritics too: https://ideone.com/dhJDqm (`(?<!\pL)\pM|[^\pL\pN\pM]` works: https://ideone.com/4phaIF )